# Getting a screen displaying "GNU GRUB version 2.04" when installing Ubuntu 20.04 using a USB drive

Tags: ubuntu-20.04

I tried installing Ubuntu 20.04 alongside windows 10 using a usb (I want double boot).
I entered the boot mode and under the boot override I chose the option "UEFI: Generic Flash-Disk 1.08".
**I can already see that there is something wrong, shouldn't I have the name of the usb I am using instead?**
Anyway I entered this option and what I got was a console stating:

GNU GRUB version 2.04
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions.
Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

`grub>`

I managed to leave this screen by typing `exit`, obviously Ubuntu wasn't installed, any suggestions?